# Microsoft Velocity installation problem

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm attempting to intall the CTP3 bits on a medium CPU 32-bit EC2 instance running Windows Server 2003 Datacenter Edition. I am using SQL server to store my configuration (on a separate machine). I am able to enter the DB connection string and I see that the database tables are created and the connection test is successful.  I set it to be a small (1-4) instance and modified the cache size to be 256.  When I click 'Save and Close' it appears to be working and then displays an error message "Error: No such host is known".  At that point, the installer seems to be done.  I can tweak values but 'Save and Close' no longer does anything.  Note, I also did try using a network share for my configuration location instead of the DB, and received the same error message.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Anything in the event viewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Velocity CTP 3 uses machine names (not DNS names).  Since our EC2 instances are not part of a domain Velocity isn't able to resolve machine names.  We had to modify the hosts file to add mappings for each machine name and its corresponding IP address.